# Asignar a Select2 Valor por defecto para Editar en Modal - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, select2

Estoy realizando una aplicacion **asp.net mvc** en la cual estoy usando **select2** pues bien tengo un modal en donde pretendo editar datos, y necesito que cuando cargo el modal de edición el **select2** tenga seleccionado el valor a editar.

He probado el siguiente código pero no he tenido éxito.

Método con el que cargo el **select2**

```
public JsonResult getEmployees(string username)
{

    var Employees_ddl = (from e in db.Employees select new { id = e.EmployeeID, text = e.Login }).ToList();
    if (username != null)
    {
        //Data filtrada
        Employees_ddl = (from e in db.Employees where e.FirstName.Contains(username) select new { id = e.EmployeeID, text = e.Login }).ToList();
    }

    return Json(Employees_ddl, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

Luego el usuario puede seleccionar un registro por medio de un `datatable` para edición(modal) pero no encuentro la manera de cuando cargue el modal de edición el `select` cargue con el valor seleccionado

```
    $("#employees").select2({


        placeholder: "----Select Employee----",

        allowClear: true,
        theme: 'bootstrap4',
        ajax: {

            url: "/Empleados/getEmployees", 
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    //alert(params.term);
                    username: params.term //parametro de metodo de mi controlador

                };
            },
            processResults: function (data, params) {
                return {
                    results: data
                };
            },


        }
    });

//Obtener Datos Seleccionados Datatable
$('body').on('click', '#Edit', function () {

    var row = $(this).parents('tr');

    var data = table.row(row).data();
    //obtengo valor que quiero asignar al select2
    var dato1 = data.EmployeeID;

    //asigno a select2 valor por defecto
   $("#select2").val(dato1).change();

});
```

Comment: Hola, puedo ayudarte a agregarle valores al select 2, pero creo que falta el código html del problema para poder resolverlo.

Comment: he agregado el código jqueyr con el que cargo el select2

Comment: Utiliza la propiedad o attr selected -   `$(this).attr('selected', 'selected');`  Revisa este enlace (http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/tD9Tv/1/)

Comment: @eduardoflores contra que comparas para seleccionar el valor por defecto ??

Comment: @FRANCISCO J. BLANCO como así, no entiendo que tengo que comparar? ya tengo el la función ajax para llenar el select2 y también capturo el id del item seleccionado por el usuario.

Comment: @eduardoflores si ya tienes el id tiene que reconocer cual es el registro para que a ese registro que le vas a cargar al select le pongas la propiedad attr selectd